# Rails query where dates are greater than or less than two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model where I am trying to come up with a query where I wanna select data if the `starts_at` is greater than today and the `ends_at` is less than today. The other caveat is checking if either one of those dates a NULL and if they aren't then the dates need to be checked against todays date also.

```rb
my_model.where("? >= starts_at AND ? <= ends_at OR (starts_at IS NULL OR ends_at IS NULL)", Ti
me.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day)
```

That code seems to pull back data sometimes and other times it doesn't.

** UPDATE **

Here are a few code examples

```rb
=>   Menu Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "menus".* FROM "menus" WHERE "menus"."account_id" = $1 AND ('2021-09-24 00:00:00' >= starts_at AND '2021-09-24 23:59:59.999999' <= ends_at OR (starts_at IS NULL OR ends_at IS NULL))  [["account_id", 1]]
[#<Menu:0x00005635d5657028
  id: 4,
  menu_type: "standard",
  name: "Promo Menu",
  starts_at: Fri, 24 Sep 2021 00:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00,
  ends_at: Fri, 01 Oct 2021 15:19:32.075844000 UTC +00:00,
  never_ends: false,
  account_id: 1,
  created_at: Fri, 24 Sep 2021 00:37:44.127698000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 24 Sep 2021 16:03:06.558332000 UTC +00:00,
  available: true>]
```

The above loads menus correctly, but heres a menu with a `starts_at` and `ends_at` within the query time frame and doesn't return

```rb
=> #<Menu:0x00005635d56d6e40
 id: 1,
 menu_type: "standard",
 name: "Main Menu",
 starts_at: Fri, 24 Sep 2021 00:37:43.512403000 UTC +00:00,
 ends_at: Sat, 25 Sep 2021 17:46:13.450433000 UTC +00:00,
 never_ends: false,
 account_id: 1,
 created_at: Fri, 24 Sep 2021 00:37:43.532613000 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Fri, 24 Sep 2021 17:46:13.455113000 UTC +00:00,
 available: true>
```

Comment: So the condition is `? between starts_at and ends_at` or `starts_at is null` or `ends_at is null`? Any of those three?

Comment: @muistooshort yes any of those three

Comment: @muistooshort I updated the question above to include some data/queries

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is correct. I guess you couldn't get the records sometimes because of the time zone. What's the timezone of the Rails app?

Comment: Thats my suspicion too. I think when the record(s) are edited on the front-end, the app isn't storing the time in UTC